# Unable to read QGIS 3.0.2 project file (*.qgs) with blank layout

Tags: qgis-3, qgs

I have two *.qgs files created using QGIS 3.0.2. one of them is absolutely new (empty) project and another one is the same as empty but with blank layout.

[Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00016988556883034435) you can download my *.qgs files.

I tried to open them with PyQGIS - the empty one reads fine, the one with blank layout crashes the script with an error:

```
 empty_project:
Clearing...OK
Create instance...OK project.fileName= 
Reading project...OK project.fileName= C:/QGIS_TEST/empty_project.qgs

 project_with_empty_layout:
Clearing...OK
Create instance...OK project.fileName= 

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

**What can cause the problem?**

Here is the code:

```python
import qgis.core

def main(project_path):
    print('Clearing...', end='')
    qgis.core.QgsProject.instance().clear()
    print('OK')

    print('Create instance...', end='')
    project = qgis.core.QgsProject.instance()
    print('OK ', end='')
    print('project.fileName=', project.fileName())

    print('Reading project...', end='')
    project.read(project_path)
    print('OK ', end='')
    print('project.fileName=', project.fileName())

if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    empty_project = r"C:\QGIS_TEST\empty_project.qgs"
    project_with_empty_layout = r"C:\QGIS_TEST\project_with_empty_layout.qgs"

    print('\n empty_project:')
    main(empty_project)

    print('\n project_with_empty_layout:')
    main(project_with_empty_layout)

    print('OK!')
```

Comment: This 1073741819 error seems to be related to windows 10

Comment: Similar behaviour on Ubuntu - segmentation fault on trying to load the empty project file. Note these load into a running QGIS  okay, so perhaps the python code isn't doing sufficient initialisation...

Comment: @Spacedman But empty project loads well.

Comment: @Albert I use windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `QgsApplication` object in your code. Adding this one line to your `main` fixes this:

```
def main(project_path):

   qgs = qgis.core.QgsApplication([], False)
```

why does it work for the empty project? Probably just luck - Qgis isn't doing as much when it gets an empty project file than when it gets the one with the layout, so its not hitting the problem. But I would always create a `QgsApplication` object.

PyQGIS tutorials also suggest you need:

```
# load providers
qgs.initQgis()
```

which might apply if you are trying to load data via providers.

Comment: QgsApplication helped. Also setting the following environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%QTDIR%\plugins\platforms\ ` worked for me to handle an error `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin windows. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.`